# HttpWebRequest.Address vs HttpWebResponse.ResponseUri

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse, system.net

Whats the difference between these two properties?

To put into context, I am determining if a redirect occurs if our ResponseUri != RequestUri.

While a redirect occurs regardless the url http://adage.com/adages/article?article_id=140560 will provide a different ResponseUri (http://adage.com/adages/post.php) than the Address (http://adage.com/adages/post?article_id=140560).

It appears the ResponseUri takes the Content-Location header and uses it while the Address maintains the correct location.

Would it be correct to compare the RequestUri to the HttpWebRequest.Address to check for redirects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, comparing `request.RequestUri` and `request.Address` is the way to go. At least in [Mono](http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/viewvc/trunk/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs) `response.ResponseUri` is the same as `request.Address`.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I found it while researching this topic and noticed it wasn't actually answered correctly.

While `HttpWebRequest.Address` and `HttpWebResponse.ResponseUri` **should** always be the same, here is the difference:

- `HttpWebResponse.Address` will return the Uri of the page actually responding
- `HttpWebResponse.ResponseUri` will return the value of the `Content-Location` header (if present). While the documentation doesn't explicitly state what happens if the `Content-Location` header is not present, it is assumed it will use the same value as `Address`.

Remember HTTP headers can be forged, so Microsoft recommends using `Address` instead of `ResponseUri` for security reasons.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.responseuri.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about setting request.AllowAutoRedirect=false and then reissuing the request on a redirect?

The Uri comparison should also work fine, although I am not sure of all the edge cases

Comment: I have considered setting the AllowAutoRedirect to false, however if I am able to handle the redirect with the current comparison I would venture for that.